# Generate OTP and verify feature for dev/qa environments

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

Our application backend is an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API, frontend is React.

I need to generate an OTP and send to a valid mobile phone number and then verify it. Is this not feasible for an application deployed in lower environment like dev or qa?

Are there any C# and/or React libraries that can help simulate this feature on dev/qa environments?

Comment: Why not feasible? Wire dev up to the same SMS service as prod; the usage will be so low the cost is insignificant and it helps prove it all works prior to hitting prod

Comment: Testing on dev or qa once or twice is ok but irritating and focus diverting for dev/ qa if they are forced to punch in every few minutes